# MSAL Authentication token caching in DB

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, integration, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-teams, msal.js

I'm using Authentication code flow for the purpose of my integration. Employing MSAL4j as my library.

Once I get the access token using the ***acquireToken / acquireTokenSilently*** method, many of the examples suggest token caching on the session itself. But instead I want to persist it on DB. In that manner, if my application goes down and starts again, I don't require my user to authorize my azure application again.

Any examples on how to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to do it. You keep the refresh token, and exchange that for a new access token

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes.. I hope I'm familiar with that concept. Once the access token is expired, refresh token need to be used to fetch a new access token. This is done by msal library by storing in token cache. My doubt is, can we store it in DB.

Comment: @Foo - could you please check if [Custom token cache serialization in MSAL for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-java-token-cache-serialization) helps?

Comment: Thanks. Yes.. I saw this. Any example implementations to refer to ?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2155#issuecomment-678472376) it was a design choice to not exposing the access token.
You could instead use one cache per user, store it in your db and treat it as it was your access token, using the `acquireToken / acquireTokenSilently` pair.

This would mean that:

- When the user registers for the first time you would use the `acquireToken` flow, serialize and store the cache obtained with `client.getTokenCache()` function.

```
    getTokenFromCode(code, userId) {
      await client.acquireTokenByCode(params);

      // get cache after retrieving the token and store it in your db
      const cache = client.getTokenCache().serialize();
      await saveCacheForUserFromDB(userId,  cache);
    }
```

- When you have to verify the user has the permissions you ask your db for the cache associated with the user, if there's the cache you can deserialize your cache in a new client and then proceed with the normal `acquireTokenSilently` flow like below.

```
      async getTokenFromCache(cache) {
        //deserializing cache into a new client
        const client = this.getAuthClient();
        const newCache = client.getTokenCache();
        newCache.deserialize(cache);

        //get all accounts stored in cache, which should only be the one of the user
        const accounts = await cache.getAllAccounts();

        //proceed with your silentFlow as the tokens where stored in memory and not in db
        const silentRequest = {
          scopes: this.scopes,
          account: accounts[0]
      };

      const silentResult = await  this.client.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest);
      return silentResult.accessToken;
    }
```

- Finally, you can create the graph `Client` with the `accessToken` you got from the `acquireTokenSilently` flow:

```
      const cache = await getCacheForUserFromDB(user);
      const authProvider = {
        getAccessToken: async () => getTokenFromCache(cache),
      };
      const client = Client.initWithMiddleware({ authProvider });
```